# How to reference an optional ACL

Tags: varnish-vcl

I want to use the same Custom VCL in any environment (staging, prod, etc.).  An ACL may exist in one put not the other.  I want to do something like:

```
 acl local {
   "192.168.1.0"/24; /* everyone on the local network */
 }

 sub vcl_recv {
   if (local && req.http.Fastly-Client-IP !~ local) {
     error 403 "Forbidden";
   }
 }
```

The problem is that the VCL compiler does not think *local* is a variable name so the compilation fails.  Is there a way to check if the local acl exists first before testing whether the Client IP is in the whitelist?